# Video capture in android in background in phoneGap with minimized recording screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, video-capture

I tried the following code. I want to record video in background and store in SD card. I don't want to do manual start recording and stop. Is it possible to record video with or without API in PhoneGap.
I want record video in background

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Video</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // A button will call this function
    function captureVideo() {
        // Launch device video recording application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 3 video clips
        alert("captureVideo");
        var options = {
            limit : 2,
            duration : 10
        };
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError,
                options);
    }
    // Called when capture operation is finished
    function captureSuccess(
    mediaFiles) {
        alert("captureSuccess   ");
        var i, len;
        alert(mediaFiles.length);
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
    }
    // Called if something bad happens.
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');

    }
    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        alert("uploadFile");
        var ft = new FileTransfer(), path = mediaFile.fullPath, name = mediaFile.name;
        alert("path:" + path);
        alert("name:" + name);
        ft.upload(path, "http://my.domain.com/upload.php", function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        }, {
            fileName : name
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do the task in background using this `document.addEventListener("pause", captureVideo, false);` but the video is not capture automatically you need to start manually.

Comment: I don't think the OS would even let you do this unless you had root access/permissions because of security concerns.  What you are asking for is the ability to record, capture, and upload video without the user even knowing.

Comment: Do u give demo how to record video in background using this document.addEventListener("pause", captureVideo, false);

Answer (score 0):

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", start_here, false);`

`function start_here(){captureVideo();}`

function is called when ever app is launched and video records automatically.
and after sending again start recording...

```
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
           alert("uploadFile");
            var ft = new FileTransfer(), path = mediaFile.fullPath, name = mediaFile.name;
            alert("path:" + path);
            alert("name:" + name);
            ft.upload(path, "http://my.domain.com/upload.php", function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            }, {
                fileName : name
            });
start_here;   /*just call the instance. here is the change*/       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can record video with minimized app or even when screen is off by [cordova\phonegap\ionic plugin](https://github.com/pavelety/backgroundvideo)

It's a fork, but main repo can't record video "in background" (in spite of the name).

When it starts, it automatically chooses, where to store video, by size of available space on SD and internal disk.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-backgroundvideo

var fileName = new Date().getTime() + '';
cordova.plugins.backgroundvideo.start(fileName, 'back', true, null, null);

cordova.plugins.backgroundvideo.stop(function (filePath) {
    alert(filePath);
  }, function (error) {
    alert('Error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```